# UNITY : Ball showing odd behaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Ball(sphere) and a floor in my game scene. `Ball.cs` is attached to the ball to control its movement in the game(Ball only moves in the vertical direction). Both Ball and floor have colliders attached to them and whenever ball touches the floor, the game should ideally end.

**OnCollisionEnter2D** Method from the `Ball.cs` script.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        // Zero out the ball's velocity
        rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        // If the ball collides with something set it to dead...
        isDead = true;
        //...and tell the game control about it.
        GameController.instance.PlayerDied();
    }
```

**Update** function

```
    void Update () {

    //Don't allow control if the bird has died.
    if (isDead == false)
    {
        //Look for input to trigger a "flap".
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {

            //...zero out the birds current y velocity before...
            rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            //  new Vector2(rb2d.velocity.x, 0);
            //..giving the bird some upward force.
            rb2d.AddForce(new Vector2(0, upForce));
        }
    }


}
```

But what's happening is whenever ball touches the ground, it starts rolling on the ground. It moves few units on `+X-axis` then rolls back and then ultimately stops.

[image]

`position.X` should ideally be 0(as the ball is moving only in `Y-axis` and it is during the game)  but as soon as ball collides with the floor it starts moving.

I am new to Unity and I have no idea what is wrong.

Why is this happening?

**EDIT**:
Programmer's answer does work but I still don't understand where the horizontal velocity is coming from(there is horizontal velocity component associated with the ball). I need to know why ball is moving in horizontal direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I noticed that you are setting `isDead` to true when collision happens. If you don't want the ball to move again then set velocity to `Vector2.zero;` in the `Update` **not only** in the `OnCollisionEnter2D` function. Do this only if `isDead` is true.

```
void Update()
{
    if (isDead)
    {
        rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }
}
```

Another option is to freeze the constraints when the collision happens. If you want the ball to start rolling again then unfreeze it.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    //Zero out the ball's velocity
    rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;

    //Freeze constraints
    rb2d.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeAll;

    // If the ball collides with something set it to dead...
    isDead = true;
    //...and tell the game control about it.
    GameController.instance.PlayerDied();
}
```

Execute `rb2d.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.None;` to unfreeze it after.

Comment: " If you don't want the ball to move again then set velocity to Vector2.zero; in the Update not only in the OnCollisionEnter2D function. Do this only if isDead is true"  - I am checking isDead condition in my Update method. I have updated my question and added the Update method too.

Comment: You are checking if `isDead` is false. I am checking if it is true. `if (isDead)` is the-same as `if (isDead ==true)`. Just add `if (isDead)
    {
        rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }` inside the `Update` function. Right now, you have not done that. Also, if that doesn't work, use my second solution

Comment: It's working fine now after adding that condition. But why was that happening? and thank you :)

Comment: Because you are **now** setting the ball velocity to `Vector2.zero;` **every frame** when the player is *dead* so it can't really move no matter what type of force is pushing it. Also, if any object collides with the, instead of moving, the velocity becomes 0 in next frame.

Comment: I understand why it's not moving now but what I don't understand is that why was it moving earlier. I zeroed the velocity in onCollisionEnter2D() and in update() there were no forces to move the ball in horizontal direction..

Comment: Maybe the key was still being held down even after the collision so `rb2d.AddForce(new Vector2(0, upForce));` was called again in next frame defeating the old `Vector2.zero`.  You can verify this by adding `Vector2.zero` inside `Input.GetMouseButtonDown` instead of `if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))` or `OnCollisionEnter2D`.

Comment: The ball only  moves in vertical direction of the button is clicked. There is no velocity in horizontal direction.

Comment: I don't know why it's only moving in horizontal pos because i don't know how you calculate your `upForce` value. The horizontal is probably how that is calculated.  As for why it is moving at-all my last comment answered that. I am sorry if you don't understand what I am saying.

Comment: I still don't know why the ball is moving in a horizontal direction. Don't worry I will accept your answer again if I don't get any appropriate answer

Comment: and `upForce` is just a public variable whose value is 250 units